# How to perform insert statements with SQL Alchemy in a structured way?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I do not know if the following is possible with SQL Alchemy and Python.

My objective is to perform an insert statement in a more structured way, using some kind of object as a row.

Some pseduocode might look like this:

```
# SQL:
#
# create table test_table (
#   id bigserial not null,
#   value varchar(256)
# );

row = # get some row object from somewhere

row.value = "some new value"

row.insert()

# or
# test_table.insert(row)
```

Is something like this possible?

The key point here is to be able to manipulate an object which represents a row in a structured way such that the values can be set using column names. In this case there is just the one column named `value`.

The `id` column, being a primary key would presumably not be manually settable. So it may be the case the syntax uses strings for column names rather than being actual field names. (Just a guess)

```
row.set_column('value', 'some new text value')
```

I couldn't find anything in the SQL Alchemy documentation which explains how to do this. I also tried asking ChatGPT - and it didn't seem to think this is possible.

The reason why I think it should be possible is that select statements work in a similarly structured way.

```
query = test_table.select()
result_proxy = connection.execute(query)
result_set = result_proxy.fetchall()
```

From the returned data it is possible to iterate over rows as tuples, to get a mapping of column names to tuple index, and do similarly structured things.

The closest I have been able to get so far for an `insert` statement is this:

```
query = test_table.insert().values(value='a text value')
```

This isn't great because it doesn't make it obvious if a column is missing, or one which doesn't exist in the table has been provided as an argument.

It also doesn't work when trying to insert multiple rows. In that case, the only option I have found is to use a list of dictionaries. Since dictionaries are totally unstructured this seems like a worse alternative.

Comment: You want something that inherits from the Mapping abstract base class in collections.abc, so that you can do `tbl.insert().values(**my_row_obj)` or `conn.execute(tbl.insert(), list_of_my_row_objs)`.

Comment: Aren't you looking for SQLAlchemy's [ORM](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html#create-objects-and-persist)?

Comment: @Dmitry I am using the ORM - `test_table.insert()` is supposed to represent `.insert()` being called on some object `test_table` which is an ORM object

Comment: @Dmitry to clarify that a bit further - the table objects are being created using reflection. I do not explicitly define them as in the first few examples from the page you have linked